# jQuery - Change color on click

Tags: jquery

I'm looking at some jQuery because I want to create a div that changes color when you click it.

And I've done that with:

```
$(function() {  
$('.star').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'yellow');

  });
});
```

And it works perfectly! 
But I want it to remove the background color, when you click it one more time. Is that possible, and how would you do something like that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eZt6C/2/ It does not fix everything not could get you somewhere

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Create a CSS class:

```
.clicked {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

and then simply [toggle that class](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) it via jQuery:

```
$('.star').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Comment: How come the box hides when using the .toggle?

Comment: @Kolind: My bad. I wrote `toggle()` (which hides/shows an element), but meant `toggleClass()` (which adds/removes a CSS class). Code is fixed. Curious that 8 up-voters didn't notice.

Comment: Cool man :o) It works. Both hides and shows the yellow color. Awesome. I'm using it for stars. I guess you got that already, right? ;)

Comment: @Kolind: I kinda gathered. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could set a flag in your click function, Then add an if statement

```
if hasBeenClicked = true;
//...background color remove
else
//....background color changed to yellow

hasBeenClicked = true;
```

Comment: This would work, but you're missing some detail on how this would work in the context of multiple `.star` elements per page, i.e. how you would manage the flag state per element.

Comment: tomalak - You're right, given the multiple items adding a class and checking for it would be the better option

Comment: You could always store the flag in the DOM object itself (as an expando property) or use jQuery `.data()` to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a CSS class would be my suggestion as well, but you can also do this to "unset" the yellow background:

```
$(this).css('background', 'inherit');
```