# Table rows not highlighting upon selection / click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple tables in my application and I want one of them to behave differently. So I tied the CSS class to a particular table Id. Here is the fiddle for the same:
http://jsfiddle.net/akshaysuri/twya05x1/
The hover functionality is working fine, but the row color does not change on clicking the row.

jQuery:

```
$("#myTable").on("click", "tr", function(e) {     
    $(this)
        .toggleClass("selected")
        .siblings(".selected")
        .removeClass("selected");
});
```

CSS:

```
#myTable tr:hover.selected td,
#myTable tr:hover td {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#myTable tr.selected td {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id='myTable'>
    <tr>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DDD</td>
        <td>EEE</td>
        <td>FFF</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @MKA Yes, I forgot to add jquery file in fiddle and the fiddle you shared is working fine but in my application I had added the file but still this code is not working in my application. Can you think of any particular reason for this behavior?

Comment: @MKA please let us know that are you testing in mobile view???

Comment: @MKA Just tried. Does not work either.

Comment: So the problem was rather elementary. Seems like the myTable was not available at the time of calling. Putting the call in $(document).ready(function() ) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one.

```js
function highlight(e) {
  if (selected[0]) selected[0].className = '';
  e.target.parentNode.className = 'selected';
}

var table = document.getElementById('myTable'),
  selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
table.onclick = highlight;
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px #DDD solid;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td>BBB</td>
    <td>CCC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DDD</td>
    <td>EEE</td>
    <td>FFF</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks. However I am more keen to know what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score -2):

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917831/jquery-change-color-on-click) - in your case, you could `.removeClass('clicked')` on all tr before the toggle.

Create a CSS class:

```
.clicked {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

and then simply [toggle that class](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) it via jQuery:

```
$('.star').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```